# python single byte function

Tags: python, casting, byte

I have a python function for setting the volume in winamp that appears to only accept a single byte as it's volume control argument. When I try to pass it a string type number it sets the volume to what appears to be very odd values. I assume this is because rather than being passed a byte it is reading the upper big-end bytes of the integer it gets passed.

My question is, how do I ensure the string type number is converted to just a single unsigned byte in the range (0 - 255) before being sent ?

```
if "volume" in message.lower():
    if (len(wordList) > 4):
        xcomPrint("Usage : \\winamp volume (0 to 100)")
    elif (Arg1.isdigit()):
        winampInstance.setVolume(Arg1)
        xcomPrint("Volume set to " + str(Arg1))
    else:
        xcomPrint("Incorrect Arguments")
        xcomPrint("Usage : \\winamp volume (0 to 100)")
```

Essentially I need to cast Arg1 to a single byte. (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using struct

```
import struct
Arg1 = struct.pack('B', 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,

actually casting it from string to int works using:

```
int(Arg1)
```

complete code:

```
if "volume" in message.lower():
    if (len(wordList) > 4):
        xcomPrint("Usage : \\winamp volume (0 to 100)")
    elif (Arg1.isdigit()):
        winampInstance.setVolume(int(Arg1))
        xcomPrint("Volume set to " + str(Arg1))
    else:
        xcomPrint("Incorrect Arguments")
        xcomPrint("Usage : \\winamp volume (0 to 100)")
```